# K8s Test - NewSimpleClientset for schemaless custom resource

Tags: go, kubernetes, istio, client-go, istio-operator

I have a method which uses client-go's `dynamic.Interface` to dynamically fetch a schemaless custom resource called `IstioOperator`.

```
iops, err := client.Dynamic().Resource(constants.IstioOperatorGVR).
    Namespace(brConfig.IstioNamespace).
    List(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{})
```

I want to unit test this function. For that I'll have to mock the `client` so that it returns the provided CR. I am trying to mock it using `NewSimpleClientset` from `k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/fake` package. When I pass the runtime object while initializing `NewSimpleClientset`, it panics with the following error:

```
panic: no kind is registered for the type v1alpha1.IstioOperator in scheme "pkg/runtime/scheme.go:100"
```

So how to register the kind `v1alpha1.IstioOperator` in the mentioned scheme for unit testing?